# iOS accessing stored files in cloud storage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, http, storage

I have a lot of files in a cloud storage website. To access them, just in the browser, I have to login and then get to the files. I'm new to iOS and I want to know if it is possible to do this within my app, so when the user clicks on a button it goes to the website and fetches the file and brings it back. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: okay, do you have any tutorials or anywhere I can learn how?

Comment: Nope. Sorry, not an Obj-C dev. But the (docs)[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/] should be of use.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but in case you were wondering I had figured it out using Amazon's S3. It works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Amazon's S3. They now have their own official SDK for iOS, so in case you find the ASI S3, try to stay away from it because it is no longer being worked on.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is: How does iCloud work.  Too broad.  http://developer.apple.com